# why is this while loop producing an infinite iteration

Tags: javascript

Hello guys please i try to create a simple loop that will run ten times, but instead, i am having this terrible infinite looping.  Here is the code

```
var numOfCars = 10,
marker = 0;
while (marker!= numOfCars.length) {
    marker++;
    console.log('I have this many cars ' + marker);
}
```

Does while loop always produce infinite iteration?

Comment: Your code produces `while(marker != undefined)` which will never stop the iteration

Comment: Apart from the `.length` problem, you should use `<` comparison instead of equality. If you're not careful you may run into edge cases where the numbers won't *exactly* equal, so the loop won't end.

Comment: you're solution is only "remove the .lenght text from your code"

Comment: my bad really what was i thinking? but i learned something though. thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from the language specification, [`Number` objects don't have a `length` property](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-number-prototype-object). Accessing a non-existing property evaluates to `undefined`. So, you are looping until `marker` is equal to `undefined`, which will never be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Beacouse `numOfCars.length`return undefined, so `marker!= numOfCars.length` is always true. Property`.length` works only for arrays and strings.

Comment: "Method .length works only for Arrays." --- this is slightly misleading and perhaps needs rewording.

Comment: lenght is not a method, it's a property. And it work on any object that define it.

Comment: Method `length` exists on several other objects, like `window`,`Set`, `Map`, `document.childNodes`, `Number`, `Array`, `String`, `Object`, `Function`, ...

Comment: Also used to get number of arguments in a function

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
var numOfCars = 10 , marker = 0;
while (marker!= numOfCars) {
    marker++;
    console.log('I have this many cars ' + marker);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Use a `for` loop:

```
var numOfCars = 3;   
for ( var marker = 0; marker < numOfCars; marker++) {
     console.log('I have this many cars ' + marker);
}
```